# React-Bootstrap Grid layout not applying

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am having issues getting grid (and row) to work in React-Bootstrap. All other 
components are functioning fine, but trying to get my items to display as a row 
has been a pain. My code:

PARENT COMPONENT

```
        <Grid>
        <Row className="show-grid">
                {this.state.results.map((movie, index) => (
                    <EachResult key={index} id={index} movie={movie} results={this.state.results} index={index} userInfo={this.props.userInfo} />
                ))}
        </Row>
        </Grid>
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
    <Col>
    <h3>{props.movie.title}</h3>
    <Image src={url} width="125" height="220" thumbnail />
    <p><strong>Summary: </strong>{props.movie.overview}</p>
    <p><strong>Rating: </strong>{props.movie.vote_average}</p>
    <Button id={props.index} onClick={addGame}>Add</Button>
    </Col>
```

I have installed React-bootstrap and I am importing each Component as such:

```
import { Grid, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
```

and

```
import {Button, Image, Col} from "react-bootstrap"
```

Sorry for the messy code! Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: I am importing the the stylesheet in my Index.html!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add Col size parameter eg.

```
 <Grid>
    <Row className="show-grid">
      <Col md={3}>
        ...
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Grid>
```

Vid [office doc](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/)

Check output DOM in browser, in most browsers F12,
in chrome check specific element with `Ctrl+Shift+C`.
Hope it will help